# How is intermediate data organized in MapReduce?

Tags: design, functional-programming

From what I understand, each mapper outputs an intermediate file. The intermediate data (data contained in each intermediate file) is then sorted by key.

Then, a reducer is assigned a key by the master. The reducer reads from the intermediate file containing the key and then calls reduce using the data it has read.

But in detail, how is the intermediate data organized? Can a data corresponding to a key be held in multiple intermediate files? What happens when there is too much data corresponding to one key to be held by a single file?

In short, how do intermediate partitions differ from intermediate files and how are these differences dealt with in the implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You might have missed one step. MapReduce works like this:

```
Map -> Shuffle -> Sort -> Reduce
```

More details about how the Shuffle & Sort step works: https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-6/shuffle-and-sort

> But in detail, how is the intermediate data organized?

Its just the output of the mapper. The actual shuffle and sort is a separate step.

> Can a data corresponding to a key be held in multiple intermediate files?

Yes, but each reducer is guaranteed to get all data corresponding to a key due to the sort step, even though different mappers can produce data corresponding to a key.

> What happens when there is too much data corresponding to one key to be held 
>   by a single file?

Would not actually matter too much. Each mapper gets a limited subset of the input, and the output will correspond in size to input for all mappers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the details on various sources on Hadoop, but since you asked here.
I think you want to have a summarization. I would summarize the answers to your two questions as follows:

1. How is intermediate data organized?
   There are 2 kinds of intermediate data, intermediate data on the mapper and intermediate data on the reducer. Intermediate data on the mapper is map from key to value. Intermediate data on reducer are ALL values of certain set of keys, partitioned by the key. If you want even more details than this then it goes into the file system organization, than I would redirect you to read the source code of Hadoop. I am not sure you need to know that, you might but I am not you so I don't know your need.
2. What happens when there is too much data about a key to be held by a single file?
   Then you keep them in multiple files BUT when you call the reducer on a certain key, you must be able to get access to all of them (all values of any key)

Hopefully, I don't miss anything here. If I do, would be very glad to be corrected.